# Intersphinx links to python 2 docs even with python 3 in intersphinx_mapping

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am building docs with sphinx (Sphinx==1.7.0) using the intersphinx extension. I noticed that it was linking to python 2 docs by default, but I preferred linking to python 3 docs, so I changed the `intersphinx_mapping` in my conf.py to the following:

```
# conf.py
...
intersphinx_mapping = {
    'python': ('https://docs.python.org/3/': None),
}
...
```

However, when I make references in my source files to python objects, I see that these still link by default to python 2. I can fix this if I prefix `str` so that it reads `python:str` (as described in the [docs](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/intersphinx.html)), which explicitly indicates which intersphinx mapping to use. For example:

```
# index.rst
:any:`str`         # surprisingly, this links to https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str
:any:`python:str`  # as expected, this links to https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str
```

For reference, this is what the docs say:

> When using the “new” format (see below), you can even force lookup in a foreign set by prefixing the link target appropriately. A link like :ref:`comparison manual <python:comparisons>` will then link to the label “comparisons” in the doc set “python”, if it exists.

My question is this: how can I make the default, unqualified intersphinx links point to python 3 docs instead of python 2 docs?

Comment: Did you `make clean` to clear out any cached files after making the configuration change?

Comment: Good call! That did it.